# How to show Notification time on RemoteViews?

Tags: android

I'm handling Android custom notification.
I knew NotificationCompat.Builder has a method named 'setShowWhen(boolean)' to show users that when the notification was came.

But I can't find the way to do same thing on RemoteViews which is a custom notification view.
Could you help me to find the way how to show the time?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

see below code.

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
            R.layout.customnotification);

    // Set Notification Title
    String strtitle = getString(R.string.customnotificationtitle);
    // Set Notification Text
    String strtext = getString(R.string.customnotificationtext);

    // Open NotificationView Class on Notification Click
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationView.class);
    // Send data to NotificationView Class
    intent.putExtra("title", strtitle);
    intent.putExtra("text", strtext);
    // Open NotificationView.java Activity
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            // Set Icon
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logosmall)
            // Set Ticker Message
            .setTicker(getString(R.string.customnotificationticker))
            // Dismiss Notification
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            // Set PendingIntent into Notification
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            // Set RemoteViews into Notification
            .setContent(remoteViews);

    // Locate and set the Image into customnotificationtext.xml ImageViews
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imagenotileft,R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imagenotiright,R.drawable.androidhappy);

    // Locate and set the Text into customnotificationtext.xml TextViews
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title,getString(R.string.customnotificationtitle));
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text,getString(R.string.customnotificationtext));

    // Create Notification Manager
    NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Build Notification with Notification Manager
    notificationmanager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

Comment: nice code but there is no any parts to handle 'time'.

Comment: you need to put text view as time in layout and then take time from date() and set it.